# Problem with alignment for hover dropdown content mobile screen

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```css
/* navigation bar dropdown */

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.15 );
        box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 0,0,0, 0.37 );
        backdrop-filter: blur( 15.0px );
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 15.0px );
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid rgba( 0,230,118, 0.18 );
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        z-index: 10;
        left: 40%;
        top: -50px;
        transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);


    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,255,0, 0.6);
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;

    }

    .dropdown:hover .drop_about {
        color: #00E676;
    }
```

```html
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">Logo</a>
            </div>
            <div id="mainListDiv" class="main_list">
                <ul class="menu_list">
                    <li><a class="menu_active" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="drop_about">About</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-content">
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="home.html#about_page">About Page</a>
                              <a class="dropdown-item" href="home.html#about_me">About Me </a>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="introduction.html">Introduction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="navTrigger">
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
                <i></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--------------->
```

I am working on my project. I am pretty new to HTML and CSS. I need some help with the alignment.
[image: Condition 1]
[image: Condition 2]

1. I need to fix that dropdown on hover. When I change screen size it goes towards right.
   The code for that is on the left.
   Forget the z-index. I was testing with it.
   Fix the code if possible.
2. Is this design good for dropdown ? If not, can you give a good design code for this.
   The thing is this works perfectly for desktop. This problem only when changing screen size to mobile.

Comment: Please post the code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: You need to add the HTML too as the problem could easily be there too.

Answer (score 0):

> you should try this-

```
 .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    left:0px
}
```

> or try using margin-left